# Having a bad day?

Tags: cipher

%#@! I have overslept!
%#@! I stubbed my toe on the bed leg!
%#@! I'm splashed from a puddle at the bus stop!
%#@! I'm late for Telecom 25 Lab!
%#@! The professor is near the door as I walk in!
%#@! My friend Kate, smiles from across the room. I scowl!

At the end of class, Kate drops this thing on my workbench. It is made from bits of wire but what does it mean?
[image: WireThing]

Comment: Is steganography involved?

Comment: @leoll2 - No.  Information is not hidden within the image.

Comment: Can steganography even be involved in a physical (non-digital) image?

Comment: 6 statements, 12 pairs of wire bits

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Got it! The code is based on:

> the 25-pair wire code and it says "WIRE (why are) YOU CROSS".
>
>  Going clockwise from 1 o'clock, the wire pair sequence is:
>  23, 9, 18, 5, 25, 15, 21, 3, 18, 15, 19, 19
>  which is then used to select letters of the alphabet

Comment: I think you're referring to this: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/25-pair_color_code  
If so, I didn't know the existence of this code and I'm happy to have learned a new thing today. Thanks!